# how to convert a string of number with trailing x's into a list of unsigned numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, string, int

I need to convert a 4 characters string to a list of unsigned numbers
for example 222X = [2220, 2221, 2222, 2223, 2224, 2225, 2226, 2227, 2228, 2229 ]
similary I should be able to convert 22XX (100 numbers), 2XXX (should result in 1000) numbeers.
Is there a quick way to do it.

I have the following solution but its not very clean..

```
std::list<unsigned> stringToCode(std::string fn)
{
   std::list<unsigned> codes;
   unsigned count = std::count(fn.begin(), fn.end(), 'X');

   unsigned none_x = std::stoi(fn);
   unsigned numbers_to_generate = std::pow(10, count);

   unsigned overrule = none_x * numbers_to_generate;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers_to_generate; i++) {
      unsigned fnumber = none_x * std::pow(10, count) + i;

      codes.push_back(fnumber);
   }

   return codes;
  }

int main() 
{

  std::string number = "4XXX";

  std::list<unsigned> codes = stringToCode(number);

   for (const auto code : codes) {
      std::cout << code << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: looks interesting.... show me the code please

Comment: How quick do you need it to be? The slowest solution should be looping from 0 and until the number of digits is larger than the string length.

Comment: _"Is there a quick way to do it."_ Sure write an appropriate algorithm to replace the X's with certain digits.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: *quick way to do it*. How are you defining quick? Fast to execute? Easy to write code? I suspect the second, but I'm just guessing.

Comment: Hint: the usual way to do this is by recursing on an index into your string. Start at the back and keep going until you hit a non-X. But with a limit of four characters a non-recursive solution would also be possible. You might find that 'quicker'.

Comment: Is `2X1X` or `X123` also possible?

Comment: @ThomasSablik No, X's appear only at the end.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, I forgot to attach my own attempt of the problem.

Comment: Create two variables: `std::string maxVal = fn; std::replace(maxVal, 'X', '9'); std::string minVal = fn; std::replace(maxVal, 'X', '0');`. Now you can loop with `for (auto i = std::stoi(minVal), j = std::stoi(maxVal); i <= j; ++i) { codes.push_back(i); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two variables:

```
std::string maxVal = fn; 
std::replace(maxVal, 'X', '9'); 
std::string minVal = fn;
std::replace(minVal, 'X', '0');
```

Now you can loop with

```
for (auto i = std::stoi(minVal), j = std::stoi(maxVal); i <= j; ++i) {
    codes.push_back(i);
}
```

The whole Code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

std::list<unsigned> stringToCode(std::string fn) {
   std::string maxVal = fn; 
   std::replace(std::begin(maxVal), std::end(maxVal), 'X', '9'); 
   std::string minVal = fn;
   std::replace(std::begin(minVal), std::end(minVal), 'X', '0');
   std::list<unsigned> codes;
   for (auto i = std::stoi(minVal), j = std::stoi(maxVal); i <= j; ++i) {
       codes.push_back(i);
   }

   return codes;
}

int main() {
  std::string number = "4XXX";

  std::list<unsigned> codes = stringToCode(number);

   for (const auto code : codes) {
      std::cout << code << std::endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```